# CVAT call to nuclio function for detector times out after 60 seconds

Tags: deep-learning, annotations, nuclio

As in the title.
I've created my custom detector, which takes a bit of time.
It seems if it runs longer than 60 seconds it times out 504 gateway timeout. Otherwise it runs through. Calling the nuclio function with curl directly seems to work without timeout.

Is there some setting to increase the timeout limit? Could not find anything, maybe some of you smart people knows?

Comment: The CVAT is not a part of OpenVINO toolkit. It is part of OpenCV and I would suggest you post your question on the [OpenCV forum](https://forum.opencv.org/) for further support.

Comment: Removed the openvino tag. Opencv forum does not have too many open threads for CVAT unfortunately, [posted it regardless](https://forum.opencv.org/t/nuclio-detector-504-gateway-timeout-after-60s/4433). Thanks for the suggestion. I would think to find some help on stackoverflow for cvat topics as well though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an older version of CVAT, you might want to refer to this [solution](https://github.com/opencv/cvat/issues/6041#issuecomment-1521908167) posted in response to a similar issue.

For newer versions of CVAT, you can follow the steps below. (Let's assume you need the timeout to be 175 seconds):

1. Add "readinessTimeoutSeconds: 175" to the function.yaml file, as shown in this example:

   ```yaml
   spec:
     description: My awesome model
     runtime: 'python:3.8'
     handler: main:handler
     eventTimeout: 3000s
     readinessTimeoutSeconds: 175
   ```
2. In your $CVAT_REPO/cvat/nginx.conf file, add the line "proxy_read_timeout 175s;" to the location / block:

   ```
   location / {
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
     proxy_read_timeout 175s;
   }
   ```